# JavaFx - Display Image loop

Tags: java, javafx

I am at a wall. I'm trying to test a simple array of images dispaly

I am getting a URL error... Ive images in the package dir and other locations with no success .

any ideas on what I am doing wrong. After this test I will convert this app to a timeline Animation

```
package javafxapplication4;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication4 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {Parent root =       

    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        // Create a pane.
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

         // set Image
        Image[] imageList = new Image[5];

        imageList[0] = new   

     Image("C:...\src\\javafxapplication4\\1.jpg");
            imageList[1] = new   
     Image("C:...JavaFXApplication4\\src\\javafxapplication4\\2.jpg");
            imageList[2] = new 
     Image("C:...JavaFXApplication4\\src\\javafxapplication4\\3.jpg");
            imageList[3] = new 
     Image("C:...JavaFXApplication4\\src\\javafxapplication4\\4.jpg");
            imageList[4] = new 
     Image("C:..JavaFXApplication4\\src\\javafxapplication4\\5.jpg");
        for (int n = 0; n > 0; n++) {

            vBox.getChildren().add(new ImageView(imageList[n]));

        }
        // Set the stage and show.
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        stage.setTitle("Image display");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

#### Console output

```
Executing   

c:...\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication4\
dist\run589201299\
JavaFXApplication4.jar using platform C:\Program
files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre/bin/java Exception in Application  start   method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.ja57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.
invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:698)
at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Exception in Application start method
at 
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1 
      (LauncherImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Invalid URL: unknown     protocol: c
at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:993)
at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:538)
at javafxapplication4.JavaFXApplication4.start(JavaFXApplication4.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
at    com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run
(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:596)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:486)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:435)
at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:988)
```

Comment: @sreuter If you edit a question, please take your time and look at the rendered result.Putting a exception inside a code block may seem like a logical thing, but the result is much harder to read than a exception in a code block: Code blocks use a monospaced font which comes closest to the font used in most consoles. Also it preserves line breaks and a bit of syntax highlighting is not that bad (but if you dont like that, add a `<!-- language: lang-none -->` , see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work ). Also code blocks are scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Image(String)` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-) expects a **URL**, not a file path. A URL includes a protocol (`file:` in this case) and requires special encoding of some characters. The easiest way to convert convert the file name to a `URL` would be to use the `File` class:

```
String fileName = ...
String fileURL = new File(fileName).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();

Image img = new Image(fileURL);
```

If your image is in the classpath however, you can also use the `ClassLoader` to get the resource url (relative to the root of the classpath) or relative to the class used, if you use [`Class.getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-):

```
String fileURL = JavaFXApplication4.class.getResource("2.jpg").toExternalForm();
```

or

```
String fileURL = JavaFXApplication4.class.getResource("/javafxapplication4/2.jpg").toExternalForm();
```

Be careful though. If you do not specify the paths correctly or did not include the resources in the classpath, the `URL` returned by `getResource` will be `null` resulting in a NPE.

Comment: Just a little addition. Don't use the toString() method. The correct method is the toExternalForm() method. The current implementation of toString returns the same result but this may change in future. (Probably not because so many programs would be wrong then :-))

Comment: @mipa I disagree regarding the could be changed part. The result is exactly defined in [the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toString--) . A change is almost out of question for reasons of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond  .  It seems that I would use imageView instead?  I'm a newbie though it seems that i should be able to  use a more simplfied path ?  :-/   Maybe it is the JAvaFx auto package initializer that I am choosing to use ..?

Comment: @user2920627 : I don't really understand that question. A `Image` contains the data, but doesn't displayed it. A `ImageView` displays that data. The part about the NPEs was only added, since there are many people who do have problems with the correct paths of the resources... If you setup your IDE correctly / include the resources when packaging the jar or whatever, there should be no problems. BTW that comment below the question addresses the guy who [submited an edit that made the question harder to read and somehow got away with it.](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35812637/2)